# Best Practice for Build Numbers with Gradle and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle

We have a small java dev environment which uses gradle, Jenkins, and Git.  We use an in-house built Gradle plugin to increment build numbers using a file to store the current number.  The build number is baked into each build as part of its version data. The build number file is checked into the git workspace for the project.

We are now adding Jenkins to the environment for CI.  Jenkins has its own build number which we can access via env var $BUILD_NUMBER.

The downside to our in-house Gradle build number plugin is that it uses a local file and thus builds by multiple developers do not sync build numbers.  If we use Jenkins BUILD_NUMBER than that is completely different sequence than the Gradle build number plugin.

What is the best practice for this type of scenario?

Comment: *The downside to our in-house Gradle build number plugin is that it uses a local file and thus builds by multiple developers do not sync build numbers* WHAT a big downside

Answer (score 0):

If you state that only builds provided by your CI are valid for future usage it seems that  you have to rely on Jenkins BUILD_NUMBER.

If you want Jenkins job BUILD_NUMBER to be started from specific value do the following:

```
Manage Jenkins -> Script Console
Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("YOUR_JOB_NAME").updateNextBuildNumber(YOUR_BUILD_NUMBER)
```

Comment: I don't think that's right for us because it there is no coordination of build number at the developer/gradle level so we could have multiple developers update Git with the same build numbers.

Comment: As for me it is not a good practice to have different binares marked with the same build number. Looks like it will provide more misunderstandings then profit. What is your use case for that?

Comment: Actually in our company we have about 20 versions of the specific service at the same time being tested somewhere. So we using following `BUILD_TIMESTAMP-GIT_COMMIT_SHORT` numbering strategy before some build will become final release version. It helps to undestand what exactly is under testing without navigating through several systems and how old is it.

Comment: So if you use BUILD_TIMESTAMP-GIT_COMMIT_SHORT your dev/test builds look like "4.5.20180901-ab123ex" where "4.5" is the major.minor version?  What do you do for the final build version?  Is that "4.5.${BUILD_NUMBER}" or some other scheme?

Comment: We are using release branching strategy - name of branch matches with release and all builds are connected with it. For subsequent operations e.g. deploy on environment we use combination of `GIT_BRANCH` and `BUILD_TIMESTAMP-GIT_COMMIT_SHORT`.